# Unable to delete a file

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-permissions

I have a program that I can't uninstall.  I get the following error:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

The program seems to be completely romoved from Program Files except for 2 files, Which is a LaTeX log file:

```
QuoteTemplate.log
QuoteTemplate.synctex.gz(busy)
```

When I try to manually delete these files I get:

> You need permission to perform this action

I click "Try Again" multiple times and it never succeeds.

When I run command prompt as administrator and try:

```
del C:\Program Files (x86)\dir\QuoteTemplate.log
```

It says `Access is Denied`.  If I try:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\dir
```

It says `Access is Denied`.

I thought that a corrupted program had a lock on the file, so I restarted the computer, then did all of the above again, with the same results.

**Update:** starting in safe mode and doing the same had the same effect.

**Update:** I was able to change the content of the files, I just couldn't delete them.  I believe it to be because of the access permissions on `dir`.  I was able to unlock `dir` using unlocker from the accepted answer.  It *seemed* that windows explorer somehow had a lock on the file, which is why restarting didn't fix the problem.  I could be wrong though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Who is the owner of those files? Have you tried to change owner to your account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple tool, called [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) can do the job easily, it disables all the 'you cannot delete ...' restrictions

Comment: the tool is also available at its [website](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)

Comment: yeah better use that one , cnet always wants to install stupid toolbars and stuff together with your software

Comment: Thanks a ton.  This solved it for me.  FWIW I downloaded from the unlocker website because cnet tried to get me to download 3 extra 3rd party toolbars etc.  I edited the link in the post to point to the better link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TAKEOWN /F filename /A` to define the `Administrator` group as owner of the file. Then try again deleting the file as `Administrator`.

Another option would be to repair the access rights of the file using `ICACLS`.

Comment: `TAKEOWN` said it was successful, but still didn't let me delete it.  I don't think I correctly figured out ICACLS.  That might have fixed it, idk.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the uninstaller EXPLICITLY as Administrator (not just simply running the program on an account that has adminitrator privs).  Otherwise you get this type of error.  I have had this happen on installs several times, and running the program as Administrator fixes the problems.